# How to prevent the entire list of items from re-rendering when only one item has changed? (React Native with hooks)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have been working with lists in React Native (hooks edition). I have a function that returns a list of items like this.

```
function toDisplay (what) {
    let dataList = [];

    if (what === 'List 1')  dataList = MobXStore.listOne
    else if (what === 'List 2') dataList = MobXStore.listTwo

    return (
        <ScrollView>
            {
                dataList ? dataList.map((item,index) =>
                    <ListItem
                        key={index + item.id}
                        containerStyle={{
                            backgroundColor: index % 2 === 0 ? 'black' : '#0a0a0a',
                        }}
                        leftAvatar={{source: {uri: item.image}, size: 75}}
                        title={item.title}
            }
        </ScrollView>
    )
}
```

When there's a change in only one time in the list. React seems to re-render the entire list. This seems to take place not each time though. Is there a way to affect only that item each time?

Comment: replace your map with a Flatlist: https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#docsNav

Answer (score 0):

It's bettter to replace your Scrollview with Flatlist:

```
                <FlatList  
                    data={dataList}  
                    renderItem={({item}) =>  <Text>{item.data}</Text>}  
                    keyExtractor={item => `listkey${item.id}`}
                />
```

And using keyExtractor prop, you avoid re-rendering the whole list every time an item is added to the list

Comment: I have tried this once before but let me try it once again.